# Spring parameter validation annotation does not validate

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a controller method like this:

```java
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class Controller
{
    @Autowired Service svc;

    @RequestMapping(value="/bar/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    BasicResponseDto<ResponseDto>
    bar(@Valid @PathVariable @Min(0) @NotNull final Long id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But it seems that the validation annotations do not have any effect. I can give it 0 and it still goes through like its OK.

What do I need to do to make it reject invalid values?

Comment: @shreyanshjogi: OK, I can try that but my annotation cleary says `@Min(0)`.

Comment: i am talking about minus 1

Comment: Zero is valid value for those validation annotations. If you consider zero to be invalid you should maybe use @Min(1)?

Comment: I have just tested with `-1` and it still does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

0 is valid for @Min(0). Change it to @Min(1) and send in 0...

Answer (score 1):

@Min is inclusive of parameter provided.